# Understand the output of XCode Instruments

Tags: xcode, profiling, xcode-instruments

I'm trying to profile my code using Instruments. What I get is something like the following window:

[image]

What I don't understand is: below `lq_cohomology`, Instruments lists `HeapMatrix::pivot`. This method is never called directly from `lq_cohomology`, but only from other functions called by `lq_cohomology`. Furthermore, I don't understand why `HeapMatrix::pivot shows up multiple times in the profile. Shouldn't that occur only a single time?